# I get an error on my code in MySQL, but I can still run that query. Revoke From Database

Tags: sql

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'Kim'@'localhost';
```

I'm trying to revoke all privileges from user "Kim", but when I write my query, FROM gets a red bar under and says that `FROM is not valid at this position, excepting EOF, ';'`
What is the problem?

Im exception all privileges to be revoked from user.

Comment: This is not a mysql error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'Kim'@'localhost';
```

This query will remove all privileges in ALL DATABASES for the user. If you want to remove privileges only on a certain DB you must write this:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* FROM 'Kim'@'localhost';
```